# How to implement a \tomorrow in latex

Tags: datetime

I was asked how to implement a `\tomorrow` macro in TeX/LaTeX. While I could come up with a reasonably good solution, working for one document class, I don't see how that could be achieved in a document class agnostic way.

I found [advdate](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/advdate), but even though the date arithmetic may be of use, it assumes a specific format for the date (which also is wrong for the locale I reside in).

Does anyone have a reasonably portable solution? Is this even possible?

Comment: If your class already defines `\today` then the only difficult part of \tomorrow is the date arithemtic, all \tommorrow can just locally add 1 day  to \year\month\day taking care of date arithemetic, and then just do \today

Comment: No unfortunately this is not possible as far as i see, since \today is edef'd in latex.ltx for example. otherwise i would have done 
`\def\tomorrow{\advance\day 1\relax\today\advance -1\relax}`

Comment: Yes latex.ltx edefs a uS english version but any language package will change that, babel's german fir example has `\def\dategerman{\def\today{\number\day.~\month@german
    \space\number\year}}
\def\dateaustrian{\def\today{\number\day.~\ifnum1=\month
  J\"anner\else \month@german\fi \space\number\year}}` so if your preamble has \dateaustian \today will give a localised today and `{add a day to \day\month\year  \today}` will give a localised tomorrow, you can't simply \advance\day 1 as you need to take account of month arithmetic, but perhaps that's what you meant?

Comment: Well yes, of course that would exclude all the date arithmetic that was fabulously solved by the other two answers (and advdate). I should have used pseudocode. I'd say adding the requirement of having to use babel is ok.

Comment: put your system clock forward by 1 day prior to compiling, then put it back... ;-( Up-vote me if you think this is the worst hack of all time.

Comment: Sorry, but this is neither a hack nor an answer.

Comment: OMG how funny...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a prototype in LaTeX3; the data about tomorrow is available in the integer variables

```
\l_tomorrow_day_int
\l_tomorrow_month_int
\l_tomorrow_year_int
```

The code follows; the final macro is just an example of how the data can be used, possibly in connection with `datetime`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_tomorrow_months_prop
\bool_new:N \l_tomorrow_leap_bool
\tl_new:N \l_tomorrow_daysinmonth_tl
\int_new:N \l_tomorrow_day_int
\int_new:N \l_tomorrow_month_int
\int_new:N \l_tomorrow_year_int

\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  1 } { 31 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  2 } { \bool_if:NTF \l_tomorrow_leap_bool { 29 } { 28 } }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  3 } { 31 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  4 } { 30 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  5 } { 31 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  6 } { 30 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  7 } { 31 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  8 } { 31 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop {  9 } { 30 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop { 10 } { 31 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop { 11 } { 30 }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_tomorrow_months_prop { 12 } { 31 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tomorrow_check_leap:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { 0 = \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } }
   {% possibly a leap year
    \int_compare:nTF { 0 = \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 100 } }
     {% possibly not a leap year
      \int_compare:nTF { 0 = \int_mod:nn { #1/100 } { 4 } }
       {% leap year
        \bool_set_true:N \l_tomorrow_leap_bool
       }
       {% not leap year
        \bool_set_false:N \l_tomorrow_leap_bool
       }
     }
     {% leap year
      \bool_set_true:N \l_tomorrow_leap_bool
     }
   }
   {% not leap year
    \bool_set_false:N \l_tomorrow_leap_bool
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tomorrow_set_tomorrow:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #2 = 2 } { \tomorrow_check_leap:n { #3 } }
  \int_set:Nn \l_tomorrow_day_int { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_tomorrow_month_int { #2 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_tomorrow_year_int { #3 }
  \__tomorrow_incr_day:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tomorrow_incr_day:
 {
  \int_incr:N \l_tomorrow_day_int
  \prop_get:NVN \g_tomorrow_months_prop \l_tomorrow_month_int \l_tomorrow_daysinmonth_tl
  \int_compare:nT
   { \l_tomorrow_day_int > \tl_use:N \l_tomorrow_daysinmonth_tl }
   {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tomorrow_day_int { 1 }
    \__tomorrow_incr_month:
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tomorrow_incr_month:
 {
  \int_incr:N \l_tomorrow_month_int
  \int_compare:nT { \l_tomorrow_month_int > 12 }
   {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tomorrow_month_int { 1 }
    \int_incr:N \l_tomorrow_year_int
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:Nn { NV,Ne }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printtomorrowof}{mmm}
 {
  \tomorrow_set_tomorrow:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  Today~it~is~
  \int_to_arabic:n { #3 }/
  \int_to_arabic:n { #2 }/
  \int_to_arabic:n { #1 },~
  tomorrow~it~is~
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_tomorrow_year_int }/
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_tomorrow_month_int }/
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_tomorrow_day_int }
  \par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printtomorrowof{\day}{\month}{\year}
\printtomorrowof{30}{10}{2012}
\printtomorrowof{31}{10}{2012}
\printtomorrowof{31}{12}{2012}
\printtomorrowof{28}{2}{2012}
\printtomorrowof{28}{2}{2013}
\printtomorrowof{28}{2}{1900}
\printtomorrowof{28}{2}{2000}

\end{document}
```

As you see, leap years are correctly recognized. Only Gregorian calendar, of course.

In order to define a suitable `\tomorrow` command, you can add (before `\ExplSyntaxOn`) a `babel` version

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\tomorrow}{}
 {
  \tomorrow_set_tomorrow:nnn { \day } { \month } { \year }
  \group_begin:
  \day = \l_tomorrow_day_int
  \month = \l_tomorrow_month_int
  \year = \l_tomorrow_year_int
  \today
  \group_end:
 }
```

or a `datetime` version (requires package `datetime`, of course)

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\tomorrow}{}
 {
  \tomorrow_set_tomorrow:nnn { \day } { \month } { \year }
  \formatdate { \l_tomorrow_day_int }
              { \l_tomorrow_month_int }
              { \l_tomorrow_year_int }
 }
```

[image]

---

This is, of course, overkill if one wants only tomorrow's date. The macros actually allow to compute any date from a given one, given the interval (positive or negative). One might make expandable also the "reverse" from a Julian date to the form "Day/Month/Year", but it would be *very* slow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\juliandate}{ m m m }
 {
  \juliandate_calc:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { \use:n }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\storejuliandate}{ s m m m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \juliandate_calc:nnnn { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { \cs_set:Npx #2 }
   }
   {
    \juliandate_calc:nnnn { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { \cs_new:Npx #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \juliandate_calc:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 % #1 = day, #2 = month, #3 = year, #4 = what to do
 {
  #4 
   {
    \int_eval:n
     {
      #1 +
      \int_div_truncate:nn { 153 * (#2 + 12 * \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } - 3) + 2 } { 5 } +
      365 * (#3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } ) +
      \int_div_truncate:nn { #3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } } { 4 } -
      \int_div_truncate:nn { #3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } } { 100 } + 
      \int_div_truncate:nn { #3 + 4800 - \int_div_truncate:nn { 14 - #2 } { 12 } } { 400 } -
      32045
     }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_g_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_dg_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_c_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_dc_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_b_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_db_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_a_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_da_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_y_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_m_tl
\tl_new:N \l__juliandate_d_tl
\int_new:N \l_juliandate_day_int
\int_new:N \l_juliandate_month_int
\int_new:N \l_juliandate_year_int

\cs_new:Npn \__juliandate_set:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:cx { l__juliandate_#1_tl } { \int_eval:n { #2 } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__juliandate_use:n #1
 {
  \tl_use:c { l__juliandate_#1_tl }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \juliandate_reverse:n #1
 {
  \__juliandate_set:nn { g }
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 + 32044 } { 146097 } }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { dg }
   { \int_mod:nn { #1 + 32044 } { 146097 } }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { c }
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { ( \int_div_truncate:nn { \__juliandate_use:n { dg } } { 36524 } + 1) * 3 } { 4 } }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { dc }
   { \__juliandate_use:n { dg } - \__juliandate_use:n { c } * 36524 }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { b }
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { \__juliandate_use:n { dc } } { 1461 } }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { db }
   { \int_mod:nn { \__juliandate_use:n { dc } } { 1461 } }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { a }
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { ( \int_div_truncate:nn { \__juliandate_use:n { db } } { 365 } + 1) * 3 } { 4 } }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { da }
   { \__juliandate_use:n { db } - \__juliandate_use:n { a } * 365 }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { y }
   {
     \__juliandate_use:n { g } * 400 + 
     \__juliandate_use:n { c } * 100 + 
     \__juliandate_use:n { b } * 4 + 
     \__juliandate_use:n { a }
    }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { m }
   { \int_div_truncate:nn { \__juliandate_use:n { da } * 5 + 308 } { 153 } - 2 }
  \__juliandate_set:nn { d }
   { \__juliandate_use:n { da } - \int_div_truncate:nn { (\__juliandate_use:n { m } + 4) * 153 } { 5 } + 122 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_juliandate_year_int
   { \__juliandate_use:n { y } - 4800 + \int_div_truncate:nn { \__juliandate_use:n { m } + 2 } { 12 } }
  \int_set:Nn \l_juliandate_month_int
   { \int_mod:nn { \__juliandate_use:n { m } + 2 } { 12 } + 1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_juliandate_day_int
   { \__juliandate_use:n { d } + 1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \juliandate_reverse:n { x }

\NewDocumentCommand{\showday}{ m }
 {
  \juliandate_reverse:n { #1 }
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_juliandate_day_int }-
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_juliandate_month_int }-
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_juliandate_year_int }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\tomorrow}{ }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \juliandate_reverse:x { \juliandate_calc:nnnn { \day + 1 } { \month } { \year } { \use:n } }
  \day = \l_juliandate_day_int
  \month = \l_juliandate_month_int
  \year = \l_juliandate_year_int
  \today
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\tomorrowof}{ m m m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \juliandate_reverse:x { \juliandate_calc:nnnn { #1 + 1 } { #2 } { #3 } { \use:n } }
  \day = \l_juliandate_day_int
  \month = \l_juliandate_month_int
  \year = \l_juliandate_year_int
  \today
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\juliandate{18}{12}{2012}

\storejuliandate*{\x}{18}{12}{2012}\x

\storejuliandate*{\x}{1}{1}{1900}\x

\showday{2456280}

\showday{2415021}

\tomorrow

\tomorrowof{31}{12}{2012}

\tomorrowof{28}{2}{2012}

\tomorrowof{29}{2}{2012}

\tomorrowof{28}{2}{2013}

\tomorrowof{28}{2}{1900}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is great work on the arithmetic. The problem, as I stated above, is to make it look like what would have been produced by today, which is affected by the documentclass, babel and a few other packages.

Comment: @Max so the \tomorrow should not take any arguments. You want a command which uses \today and adds a day, without having to specify which day it is now, is that right?

Comment: Yes, ideally. This would be accomplished by `\def\newtomorrow{\tomorrow{\day}{\month}{\year}` already, but it would be wrong for a german, french or american document. While it's trivial to adjust the tomorrow macro on a per user/country/document basis, the solution i am looking for would work with every documentclass and combination of packages. This may not be possible though.

Comment: @Max I've shown how you can integrate the macros with `babel` or `datetime`

Comment: yes thank you very much. I am having trouble compiling it though. I get 

`! Command `\prop_get:Nn' not yet defined!`

on line

`l.72 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:Nn`

I haven't really done much with latex3/expl3 yet and started reading the code for a couple of hours. I only seem to have `\prop_get:NnN` which isn't consistent with your line i think. This is under texlive 2012, do i need an updated package?

Comment: @Max Yes, you need to update to the latest `l3kernel` version.

Comment: Note that as of September 2014, `\prop_get:Nn` has been renamed to `\prop_item:Nn`

Comment: @egreg The code seems to be broken... `Use of \??? doesn't match its definition. <argument> \???  ! LaTeX Error: A property list was misused.
l.95 \printtomorrowof{30}{10}{2012}`

Comment: @egreg I am talking about the 1st code.

Comment: @projetmbc Thanks for noting, fixed.

Answer (score 33):

Just a quick cook-up

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}

\newcount\pgfdatecount
\newcommand{\tomorrow}{%
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-\month-\day+1}{\pgfdatecount}
\pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\the\pgfdatecount}{\myyear}{\mymonth}{\myday}
\pgfcalendarmonthname{\mymonth}\space\myday,\space\myyear%
}

\begin{document}

\today~ is the day before tomorrow.\par
\tomorrow~ is the day after today.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding weekday names etc. is also possible. You can check the manual. This is, as far as I can paranoi(?!), independent from the class but the month names are fixed. If you like you can introduce them too but ISO dates rulaz just because of this.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use `datenumber` package.

On preamble

```
\usepackage{datenumber}
\setdatetoday
\addtocounter{datenumber}{1}%
\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
```

In the document

> today is `\today`
>   tomorrow is `\datedate`

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered a while ago, but I didn't see a plain TeX solution here yet. Hopefully it will be useful to somebody.

```
\let\mydatesep=-
\newcount\advancedday
\newcount\daysinthismonth
\newcount\tempyear
\newcount\ttempyear
\def\advancedatebydays#1{%
\advancedday=\number\day%
\advance\advancedday by #1%
\tempyear=\number\year%
\ttempyear=\tempyear%
\loop%
\loop%
\ifnum\ttempyear>4 %
  \advance\ttempyear by-4 %
\repeat%
\ifnum\month=2 %
  \ifnum\ttempyear=4 %
    \daysinthismonth=29 %
  \else%
    \daysinthismonth=28 %
  \fi%
\else%
  \ifodd\month%
    \ifnum\month<8 %
      \daysinthismonth=30 %
    \else%
      \daysinthismonth=31 %
    \fi%
  \else%
    \ifnum\number\month>7 %
      \daysinthismonth=31 %
    \else%
      \daysinthismonth=30 %
    \fi%
  \fi%
\fi%
\ifnum\advancedday>\daysinthismonth%
  \ifnum\month=12 %
    \advance \tempyear by 1 %
    \advance \ttempyear by 1 %
    \advance \advancedday by -\daysinthismonth%
    \advance \month by -11 %
  \else%
    \advance \advancedday by -\daysinthismonth%
    \advance \month by 1 %
  \fi%
\repeat%
\number\advancedday\mydatesep\number\month\mydatesep\number\tempyear%
}%

\advancedatebydays{302}
\bye
```