# How can I convert a datetime month name to uppercase?

Tags: capitalization, datetime, datetime2, uppercase

I'm trying to create a date style that results in

> 01 JUN 2020

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[showseconds=false,useregional=text,calc]{datetime2}
\DTMnewdatestyle{mydatestyle}
{
    \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{
        \DTMtwodigits{##3} \MakeUppercase{\DTMshortmonthname{##2}} ##1}
    \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}
}
\begin{document}

\DTMsetdatestyle{mydatestyle}
\today

\end{document}
```

but no matter where I wrap `\MakeUppercase` around it, it gives me

> 01 Jun 2020

Is there a way to simply change the case of the date without needing to [redefine the month names?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145692/215974) (which I cannot get to work with my `datetime2` example, while the answers there work out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `\DTMshortmonthname` (like many others) are defined via `datetime2-calc` package and are [robust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764). You can either use the language-specific alternative `\DTMenglishshortmonthname` or define your own `\MYshortmonthname` that isn't robust and will work with `\MyUppercase`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[showseconds=false,useregional=text,calc]{datetime2}

\DTMnewdatestyle{mydatestyle}{%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \DTMtwodigits{##3} \MakeUppercase{\MYshortmonthname{##2}} ##1}% ...or \DTMenglishshortmonthname
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\newcommand{\MYshortmonthname}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1% 0
    \or Jan%
    \or Feb%
    \or Mar%
    \or Apr%
    \or May%
    \or Jun%
    \or Jul%
    \or Aug%
    \or Sep%
    \or Oct%
    \or Nov%
    \or Dec%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\DTMsetdatestyle{mydatestyle}
\today

\end{document}
```